# Eloquent Model doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I created my first model, run the correct path in browser and get error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Call to undefined method Post::all()
```

Why is that happening? Im learning laravel with course and the teacher dont have my problem with undefined method :(

I generated model by artisan:

```
php artisan generate:model Post
```

My controller:

```
public function listing()
    {
       $posts = Post::all();
       return View::make('post.listing', compact('posts'));
    }
```

My model:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

}
```

My View:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <h1>{{{ $post->title }}}</h1>
@endforeach

@stopassola
```

How Can I fix this? Of Course I have table named posts in database.

Comment: I used `composer dumpautoload` and found out that have 2 classes named Post. Problem resolved.

Comment: You should add the resolution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `composer dumpautoload` and found out that have 2 classes named Post.

Problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function listing()
{
   $posts = \App\Post::all();
   return View::make('post.listing', compact('posts'));
}
```

cheers!